# Filtering a data.table by conditions passed in a list

Tags: r, data.table

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this filtering? Just trying to find a similar method to pandas query where you pass a dictionary (`kwagrs**`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat4)
```

Parameters are passed in a list here:

```
ab <- list(Clinic=TRUE, Hospital=FALSE)
ab <- sapply(ab, function(x) {
  var = names(ab)[parent.frame()$i[x]]
  sprintf('%s==%s',var,x)
})
ab <- paste(ab, collapse = ' & ')

ad <- dat4[eval(parse(text=ab)),]
```

I am looking for a programmatic way to do this subsetting:

```
subset(dat4, Clinic == TRUE & Hospital == FALSE)
```

Comment: Please post the output as well along with sample of `head(dput)` input data frame (ab).

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible example. However, you probably can get this with a join in `data.table`.  Something like `dat4[as.data.table(ab), on=names(ab)]` should do it.